# Email address getting in encoded format DB

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, vba

I'm getting the email address in encoded format like "annie@h ꇟ|（ƓƓⲘ" and i'm catching it in a string then not able to store it in server database. So how do i decode it to normal email address. or not getting which type of Encoding is it(base64/ascii/ect..).and the column type is long varchar,
machine i'm using it windows xp. I'm pulling my hair out.

Please help..

Comment: Where are you getting the emails from? And how are they "encoded" to begin with, seems to me you might be dealing with some weird charset issue.

Comment: code paste karu shakata ka?

Comment: Hi JanR,i'm not sure what i'm getting is encoded format or what else ?because half string is okay and then it wired.

Comment: Namaskar M.N.S., it's an normal query and read data from it and work find for another machine (windows 7).

Comment: What database? Do you use ODBC?

Comment: it is an SQL server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i caught the answer but i'm not sure is this the right way to do.
Now I read the record from ADODB.Recordset instead of Dataset. 
is this the right way to read data.

I don't know why Dataset give me the wired email address,But using Record set i solve the issue

Here is the code sample that i use now

```
Dim str_query = "select * from table"
Dim objRS= New ADODB.Recordset
objRS= Cn.Execute(str_query )
Do While Not objRS.EOF
    For k = 0 To objRS.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print objRS(k).Name & ": " & objRS(k).Value  
    Next
    Debug.Print "_____" 
    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

And previously I used code this

```
        Dim str_query = "select * from table"
        Dim objRS= New ADODB.Recordset
        objRS= Cn.Execute(str_query )
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter

        da.Fill(ds, objRS, "my_table")

        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("my_table").Rows


        Next
```